# How to know when dired is done if called async?

Tags: dired, async

If I am copying files using dired having previously called `(dired-async-mode)` to make it copy asynchronously, how do I know when it has successfully finished copying the files?

Comment: The status is reported from the mode line, see user option `dired-async-message-function`, it might be easily missed, since by default it shows for max 3 seconds and disappears immediately if you are hitting some keys.

Comment: @xuchunyang: Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final status information of the process is reported on the mode
line for 3 seconds, however if you enter some keys during the 3
seconds, it will disappear immediately, thus if you are using Emacs
actively, you might miss that easily.

You can change the default behavior via the user option
`dired-async-message-function`. Notes that the corresponding docstring:

> Function to use to notify result when operation finish.
>   Should take same args as `message'.

is not 100% correct, it actually takes `(text face &rest args)`, which
is not the same as `message`. Use the default value as an example, if
you want to change it. Here is another example which notifies via
voice by using say(1) which provided by macOS.

```
(setq dired-async-message-function
      (lambda (text face &rest args)
        (shell-command (format "say '%s'" (apply #'format text args)))))
```